# Update from os x 10.4 to 10.9 with time machine backup

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have a iMac (compatible with os x 10.9) running 10.4 Tiger.

How do I upgrade this to OSX 10.9 as AppStore is not available under 10.4.

I do have a time machine backup from my macbook pro running mac os x 10.9. Is it possible to import the 10.9 time machine backup to my old imac running tiger?

Comment: Do you mean update your 10.4 machine to use OSX 10.9?

Comment: yes, because in 10.4 the app store is not available, so i can not download the free 10.9 installer.

Comment: So your question is really How do I update a machine with 10.4 to 10.9?

Comment: yes thats right. Do i have to buy mac os x 10.6.8 to get the app store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a bootable Mavericks USB flash drive or DVD on your Macbook Pro (the 10.9) machine using the steps in this [Apple note](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5856?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

You can then boot your iMac off this media and install 10.9

You can connect the iMac to your Time Machine backup (e.g. plug the disk in or attack via network) and during the install tell the install to get data from the Time Machine backup.

You can't install a version of  OSX from a Time Machine backup you need to install OSX first.

An alternative is to create a bootable backup from the 10.9 machine using Carbon Copy Cloner or Superduper etc and then boot the iMac from that and restore from it.

Comment: The easiest way to create a bootable installer is [DiskMaker X](http://diskmakerx.com) the process is documented by [arstechnica.com](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-9-mavericks-usb-install-drive/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to at least buy the upgrade to Snow leopard (10.6). From that you may perform an in place upgrade to 10.9.  You may want to be sure your device supports 10.9, it has to be 2007 or later, in general.  I don't think that importing Time Machine from a newer to old version will work.